# Kendo Mobile Listview Template get mobile switch position onChange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, kendo-mobile

I'm developing a solution using kendo UI mobile there I have custom template like this

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="customListViewTemplate">

                #if(type === 'Input'){#
                   #if(status === 'true'){#

                    <a> #: name #</a><img id="alarm_indicator" src="img/bullet.png">
                   #}else{#
                    <a> #: name #</a><img id="alarm_indicator" src="img/bullet_red.png">
                   #}#
                #}else{#

                 #if(outputconfig === 'true'){#
                        #if(status === 'true'){#
                            #var i = 1 #
                            #i++#
                            #alert('rr')#
                            #localStorage.setItem(i,1)#

                            <a> #: name #</a> <input id="mobile-switch" data-role="switch" index="1" data-change="app.watchguard.switchChange"  checked="checked" data-enable="false"/>
                        #}else{#
                            #var i = 1 #
                            #i++#

                            #localStorage.setItem(i,0)#
                            <a> #: name # </a>  <input id="mobile-switch" data-role="switch" index="2"data-change="app.watchguard.switchChange"  data-enable="false"/>
                        #}#

                  #}else{#

                        #if(status === 'true'){#
                            #var a = 1 #
                            #a++#

                            #localStorage.setItem(a,1)#

                            <a> #: name #</a> <input id="mobile-switch"  data-role="switch" data-change="app.watchguard.switchChange"  checked="checked" />

                        #}else{#

                            #var a = 1 #
                            #a++#

                            #localStorage.setItem(a,0)#

                            <a> #: name # </a>  <input id="mobile-switch" data-role="switch"  index="4" data-change="app.watchguard.switchChange" />
                        #}#

                    #}#
                #}#
</script>
```

Here it loads a List view from data source with a mobile switch button on the right. (Each list item with a mobilw switch) Problem is I need to get the position of mobile switch button through on change() (ex: 0,1,2 ). How do I do that? Can some one help me :-)

Thanks

Chinthaka

Comment: #is to write JS codes because I need to check some conditions to locad the ui accordingly my problem is How I get the position of mobile switch from onChange

Comment: app.watchguard.switchChange  : namespace.switchChange = function(e){//Can I get the position of the mobile switch from e ???}